# Using for loops with dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html

On my HTML page I have a dropdown list containt the numbers 1-5. When the user selects one of these option I want my javascript to grab the option and loop through it however many times selected asking the same group of questions over.

My question is: How do I get the for loop to loop through the selected amount on the dropdown list and output the question that amount of times in the Javascript?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your last function:

```
var value = document.getElementById("value").value;

    console.log(value);

    for (var i = 0; i < value; i++)
    {
        var output = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += ("<p>What you want?</p> <select id='animal[i]'> <option value='first'>first</option> <option value='second'>second</option> </select></p>");
    }
```

Comment: Yes that it, apologies for the stupidity, I think I was over complicating this

Comment: You had two problems: `innerHTML +=` is true and `numAnumals.length` must change to `numAnimals'

Comment: Apologies, I panicked. I will upvote this answer and give it the correct mark as it does help me alot

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me and for understanding.